# @Component Spring annotation standard scope

Tags: java, spring

What's the default scope of Spring's `@Component` annotation?

If you don't define a scope at all, is it application scoped? The Spring documentation does not say anything about default scope.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> The singleton scope is the default scope in Spring.

This is said [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-singleton)

And also in the current [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes) you find

> singleton
>   (Default) Scopes a single bean definition to a single object instance per Spring IoC container.