# Spring's autowiring , new operator and confusion

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have class called Engine, and a Car.

```
class Engine {

...some params
...getters
...setters

}

class Car extends Engine {

... some params
... getters 
... setters

}
```

Now in a controller say there is a endpoint called **"./getCarDetails"**

There is a *table* which corresponds to Engine class called **engines**.

Now since for **carDetails i need engine and some other params**, i am using **engineRepository** for getting engine table's data and otherRepository from some other details data.

What i did was i made Engine class a component and autowired it. Now i have engine bean , i am setting the engine values for each cars.
for eg.

```
@Autowired
Engine engine;

for(Car car: cars){
 car.setEngineParam(engine.getEngineParam());
}
```

*The problem :-*

Each car has the same engine

But when i create the object using new operator, everything works fine.

*Question:-*

> Should i never use new operator in spring boot app ?
>
> How do i solve the current problem without new operator using
>   autowiring ?

Comment: Something is wrong with your relationship. A `Car` contains an `Engine`, not evolve from an `Engine`. Your implementation now means that a `Car` *is* an `Engine`.

Comment: that's alright, the questions is not regarding this relationship, it is about new operator and autowiring @Jai

Comment: I agree with @Jai. Also consider composition over inheritance  when describing the relationship between a car and it's engine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The engine is the same because the default scope is `SINGLETON`.

You can use `PROTOTYPE` scope to get a new bean each time it is requested from the container. You'll also need proxy because you are autowiring it in a controller and not explicitly requesting from the container. So annotate your engine class with this:-

```
@Scope(value="prototype", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

Comment: it is container which is giving me a bean, be it a controller or any other class, so what is the use of proxyMode ?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you need a proxyMode for prototype-scoped bean? Happy to upvote if you elaborate convincingly what if and what if not proxymody is set to target.

Answer (score 1):

If you need different engines everytime you request it you need a prototype-scope bean rather than your singleton @Component. This will give you a new object everytime you request it.

Alternatively if you have limited number of engines that you can name - then use named singleton beans (see @Qualifier). Downside of it is that everytime you request same named bean - you will get the same object.

Find "prototype scope" in Spring docs. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You said you made `Engine` a component:

> What i did was i made Engine class a component and autowired it. Now i have engine bean , i am setting the engine values for each cars. for eg.

It sounds like `Engine` really should be an entitiy (a domain class in your application). Leaving your domain objects lifecycle up to a dependency injection framework sounds a bit off.

`Should i never use new operator in spring boot app ?`
Never use new for a Spring managed bean (e.g. Controller, Repository, Service etc.)

`How do i solve the current problem without new operator using autowiring ?`
If you have a database, make the Engine class as an entity. Don't use autowiring for the engine class. It represents data (state in the database), and should not be treated as a dependency.

if the class in question is managed by a dependency injection framework you should never create it with `new`.

Answer (score 0):

First I think Car should not extend Engine since Car is not an engine. Car has an Engine and should be provided. Example shows via constructor but could also be setter. [@Autowire by field](https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/field-dependency-injection-considered-harmful/) is not recommended and is concidered harmfull.

```
public class Car {
  private Engine engine;
  public Car(Engine engine) {
     this.engine = engine;
  }
}
```

Regarding creating Car and Engine as [@Component they are by default singeltons in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42599768/component-spring-annotation-standard-scope/42599882) Container. Unless you only want one car with one engine in your application you have to do this in an other way.

There are several ways. You can configure as many cars as you need and give them different engines by creating them as @Bean

Create a [@Configuration](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_java_based_configuration.htm) class (called when container starts) and add cars and engines

```
@Bean
public Car ford() {return new Car(v8());}
//public Car ford(Engine v8) {return new Car(v8);} // if engines is in separate configuration file

@Bean
public Engine v8() {
  return new V8Engine(); // extends/implements Engine
}

@Bean
public Engine standard() {
  return new StandardEngine(); // extends/implements Engine
}
```

You could however create implementations like Ford, Volvo and BMW by extending/implementing Car and use @Component and @Autowire for engines.